# How to retrieve the real position of axis in matplotlib constrained layout mode

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a (2x3) subplots and forced them in `constrained_layout=True` using code below. I want to hide ax03 and created other figures in that region. For alignment purpose, I used `ax.get_position` to get the axis position of ax03, and using `add_axes()` to make a new axis. But it seems that it is *NOT* aligned as expected. From my observation, `get_position()` returns the position of axis before the layout reschedule.

Note: If I execute the code in two sections, then I can get the postion of course. I want to achive it in single one execution.

```
import matploltib.pyplot as plt

# Section 1
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(7.2, 7.2/1.68), constrained_layout=True)
axes = axes.ravel()
ax01 = axes[0]
ax02 = axes[1]
ax03 = axes[2]
ax11 = axes[3]
ax12 = axes[4]
ax13 = axes[5]

# Section 2
pos = ax03.get_position() # get the original position
width = pos.x1 - pos.x0
height = pos.y1 - pos.y0


print(ax03.get_position())
ax = fig.add_axes([pos.x0, pos.y0, width, height])
print(ax.get_position())    
# it seems the position of ax is the postion before constrained is applied.
```

Here is what I get when execute section 1 and section 2 together. Postion info:

Bbox(x0=0.6720588235294118, y0=0.53, x1=0.9000000000000001, y1=0.88)
Bbox(x0=0.6720588235294118, y0=0.53, x1=0.9000000000000001, y1=0.88)

[image]

If execute section 1, and then section 2, I get:

Bbox(x0=0.7209572530864197, y0=0.5704676577986438, x1=0.9728583333333332, y1=0.9773075117370893)
Bbox(x0=0.7209572530864197, y0=0.5704676577986438, x1=0.9728583333333332, y1=0.9773075117370893)

If I turn off constrained_layout:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(7.2, 7.2/1.68), 
constrained_layout=False)
axes = axes.ravel()
ax01 = axes[0]
ax02 = axes[1]
ax03 = axes[2]
ax11 = axes[3]
ax12 = axes[4]
ax13 = axes[5]
ax03.axis('off')

pos = ax03.get_position() # get the original position
width = pos.x1 - pos.x0
height = pos.y1 - pos.y0

print(ax03.get_position())
ax10 = fig.add_axes([pos.x0, pos.y0, width, height])
print(ax10.get_position())
```

Bbox(x0=0.6720588235294118, y0=0.53, x1=0.9000000000000001, y1=0.88)
Bbox(x0=0.6720588235294118, y0=0.53, x1=0.9000000000000001, y1=0.88)

Postion above is the  *Same* when `constrained_layout=False`

**How can I get the postion of ax03 of the new layout in one execution?**

Comment: I think this is all expected, due to constrained layout being applied at every draw of the figure. So before spending time on explaining that in detail, what exactly is the purpose of the new axes? Why not keep the old one which complies to the constrained layout automatically? Or just create a new axes at the same position in the layout, instead of at the same position in fixed coordinates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Constrained Layout will be effectuated each time the figure is drawn. Hence you would need to draw the figure first, then you can get the actual position of the axes inside of it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ((ax01, ax02, ax03),(ax11, ax12, ax13)) = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(7.2, 7.2/1.68), 
                                                            constrained_layout=True)
# draw the figure to apply constrained_layout
fig.canvas.draw()

# Section 2
pos = ax03.get_position() # get the original position
print(pos)
ax = fig.add_axes([pos.x0, pos.y0, pos.width, pos.height])
print(ax.get_position())    

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note however, that once you resize the figure again, the position becomes wrong again. So the question is, why is that position important for you? If the aim is to create a new axes on top of the existing one, one would rather put it into the same position of the same existing grid, e.g. as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ((ax01, ax02, ax03),(ax11, ax12, ax13)) = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(7.2, 7.2/1.68), 
                                                            constrained_layout=True)

gs = ax03.get_gridspec()
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,2], label="new_axes")

plt.show()
```

Then, `constrained_layout` applies to that axes as well and they will always be on top of each other.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the draw(), make the constrained_layout implementation time tangible...!!!!

Comment: I will add three axes in that subregion, I do try the gridspec and subgridspec thing, they work!. But It seems they are much slower,  and I need to fine tune the postion, I have figures with labels and image figure together, so fine tune position is important for me. the default gridspecs is good for same type of figures although.

Comment: In principle you cannot fine tune the position if constrained_layout is turned on. So the next question is, why do you think you need constrained_layout at all? Can you just do `fig.tight_layout()` once? That would speed up things dramatically. And finally, why would `subgridspec` not allow for the fine-tuning you need? It's perfectly meant to be used for cases like that.

Comment: In my usage, tight_layout is usullay implemented using plt.subplots(2, 3), for the classic grid plotting. Now, I need some complex thing in my plots. for example subplots in ax03 region. In this case subgridspec work!. It provides more flexibilty creating complex grids. However, In my big plot, I have image figures without axis, line plots with labels and ticks. the default alighment is not the optimal for me. I know I can use grid.update(left=..) to adjust the grids. But in my experience, gridspecs are much slower although acceptable.

Comment: so why not use subplots and constrained layout do the main structure, and hide the specific axis you want to add more details. and spend some time do fine tuning. All my figure size is fixed in  size. So one setting will work for me in the future.

Comment: I don't quite follow the argument. If you want to create the figure once in a single script, `fig.tight_layout()` would be enough. If you experience slow rendering, that is for sure due to the use of  `constrained_layout`.

Answer (score 1):

You did get the position of `ax03`, and the position is correct. The reason why you get the same position is because you set the position of `ax` to the exact same position as `ax03`.

```
width = pos.x1 - pos.x0
height = pos.y1 - pos.y0
```

This gets the width and height of `ax03`.

```
ax = fig.add_axes([pos.x0, pos.y0, width, height])
```

This creates a new figure with the same `x0`, `y0`, `width`, and `height` as `ax03`. They are in the same spot. Printing the positions confirms this.

Comment: The thing is the new axis is not aligned with previous one. and the position is befoe the constrained condistion is applied....I want to get the position of ax03 after constraints in single execution.

Comment: @ted930511 I think that may just be `constrained_layout=True` bugging out when it tries to constrain your plot when there are overlapping axes. If you set it to false no misalignment happens.

Comment: My theory is that the location of the plot is still the same but the display just gets messed up due to the overlap.

Comment: I add more details to my question. it seems the postion I get is before all constraints applied.

Comment: @ted930511 hold up, for me if `constrained_layout=False` the position doesn't look like what you have above. There's no misalignment.

Comment: I dont mean misalignment when constrained layout is off, it definitely will aligned. I mean the position I get is the same no matter constrained_layout is True of False...Which means the position is set before constrained_layout is applied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188085/discussion-between-primusa-and-ted930511).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs  = plt.subplots(2, 3, constrained_layout=True)

gs = axs[0, -1].get_gridspec()
axs[0, -1].remove()

gs2 = gs[0, -1].subgridspec(3, 3)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        fig.add_subplot(gs2[i, j])
plt.show()
```

gives me:

[image]

It takes 0.95s without constrained layout and 1.3s with constrained layout on my machine.